# jqueryui sortable adjusting serialize

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have my sortable setup like this:

```
$('.qgroups').sortable({
  axis: 'y',
  handle: '.handle',
  update: function() {
    return $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'));
  }
});
```

and it's working nicely, the serialize returns me:

```
Parameters: {"question"=>["8", "2", "9"]}
```

which is what I want. Now however, I'd be able to a hash called user for example so it looks something like this:

```
Parameters: {"question"=>["8", "2", "9"], "user" => ["12"]}
```

now I store the user value in a `data-user`on the div where I also retrieve the `update_url. How can I add this into the serialize?

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery's extend method.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

So something like this

```
$.extend($(this).sortable('serialize'), $(this).data('user'))
```

Comment: That gives me this: {"0"=>"u", "1"=>"s", "2"=>"e", "3"=>"r", "4"=>"_", "5"=>"3"}

Comment: `$.extend($(this).sortable('serialize'), {user: $(this).data('user')})`



Looks like you're storing user data like `user_3`, consider storing just the number or you will have to use substring to extract it

Comment: That returned Parameters: {"user"=>"user_1"} , so question params dissapeared , I'm storing it like that because that's how they prefer it: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize

Comment: Okay. To achieve the format in your original post, this should work: 
`{user: [$(this).data('user').substring(5, $(this).data('user').length)]}`